# MEAN - Http Put Request 404 Not Found

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express, mean-stack

I am building a MEAN stack application. I am receiving a 404 response when submitting a put request.This only occurs when I am trying to edit a booking. It does not successfully edit a specific booking.
Client Side

booking.service.ts

```
 getBooking(id: string) {
    return this.http.get<{ _id: string, title: string, content: string }>("http://localhost:3000/api/bookings/" + id);
  }

 updateBooking(id: string, title: string, content: string){
    const booking: Booking = { id: id, title: title, content: content };
    this.http.put("http://localhost:3000/api/bookings/" + id, booking)
    .subscribe((response) => {
      const id = booking.id;
      const updateBook = [...this.bookings];
      const oldBookingIndex = updateBook.findIndex(b => b.id === id);
      updateBook[oldBookingIndex] = booking;
      this.bookings = updateBook;
      this.bookingUpdate.next([...this.bookings]);
    });
  }
```

booking-create.component.html

```
<mat-card>
  <form (submit)="onSaveBooking(bookingForm)" #bookingForm="ngForm">
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput type="date" name="title" [ngModel]="booking?.title"
      required minlength="3"
      #title="ngModel"
      placeholder="Date">
      <mat-error *ngIf="title.invalid">Please enter title</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field>
      <textarea matInput  name="content" [ngModel]="booking?.content" required
      #content="ngModel" placeholder="Golf Course"></textarea>
      <mat-error *ngIf="content.invalid">Please enter content</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
    <hr>
    <button mat-button
    color="accent"
    type="submit">Save Booking</button>
  </form>
</mat-card>
```

booking-create.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

//import {Booking } from '../booking-list/booking.model';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { BookingService } from '../booking.service';
import { ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from '@angular/router';
import { Booking } from '../booking-list/booking.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-booking-create',
  templateUrl: './booking-create.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./booking-create.component.css']
})
export class BookingCreateComponent implements OnInit {

  enteredTitle = '';
  enteredContent = '';
  booking: Booking;
  private mode = 'create';
  private bookingId: string;


  constructor(public bookingService: BookingService, public route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe((paramMap: ParamMap) => {
      if (paramMap.has('bookingId')){
        this.mode = 'edit';
        this.bookingId = paramMap.get('bookingId');
        this.bookingService.getBooking(this.bookingId).subscribe(bookingData => {
          this.booking = {id: bookingData._id, title: bookingData.title, content: bookingData.content};
        });
      }
      else {
        this.mode = 'create';
        this.bookingId = null;
      }
    });
  }


  //bookingCreated = new EventEmitter<Booking>();

  onSaveBooking(form: NgForm){
    if(form.invalid){
      return;
    }
    if (this.mode === 'create') {
      this.bookingService.addBooking(form.value.title, form.value.content);
    }
    else {
      this.bookingService.updateBooking(this.bookingId, form.value.title, form.value.content);
    }
      form.resetForm();
  }

}
```

Server side
app.js

```
app.get("/api/bookings/:id", (req, res, next) => {
  Booking.findById(req.params.id).then(booking => {
    if (booking) {
      res.status(200).json(booking);
    }
    else {
      res.status(404).json({ message: 'Booking not found'});
    }
  })
});

 app.put("/api/bookings/:id", (req, res, next) => {
    const booking = new Booking({
      _id: req.body.id,
      title: req.body.title,
      content: req.body.content
    });
    Booking.updateOne({_id: req.params.id}, booking).then(result => {
      console.log(result);
      res.status(200).json({message: 'Booking updated'});
    });
  });
```

Comment: This is a bit confusing. Are you receiving a 404 for the route not found or a 404 from the endpoint for "booking not found"?

Comment: Yes I am receiving a 404 from the endpoint when trying to update a specific booking..

Comment: In that case, check your parameters that you're supplying to the Mongo query (console.log) and make sure the ID there is an actual ID in the database. Or catch an error from the find method to see what went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess when you are use using 'booking' in this line that throws an issue

```
    Booking.updateOne({_id: req.params.id}, booking).then(result => {
```

You can try just to use a single params to see if it is working

```
   {$set: {"title": req.body.title}}
```

Not sure if the whole object can be passed like that.